# The rectangle contour in $p.v. \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ax}}{1+e^x} dx$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis, proof-explanation

Consider finding the principal value of $$p.v. \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ax}}{1+e^x} dx$$

> [image]
>   [image]

Q1: It is said the top path $\gamma_3$ is accessed by multiplying $-e^{2\pi i a}$. So why is the integral being multiple by $e^{2\pi i a}$ and no vertical translation is made for $\gamma_1$

PS: Do coming up with these contours take some ingenuity? Because I don't think I would think about using a rectangle had I not seen the solution.

PSS: The Residue theorem gives $\pi/4$

Comment: Q1: $\int_{\gamma_3} \frac{e^{az}}{1+e^{z}} dz = \int_{\rho}^{-\rho} \frac{e^{a(x+2\pi i}}{1+e^{x + 2\pi i}}  = e^{2a\pi i}\int_{\rho}^{-\rho} \frac{e^{ax}}{1+e^{x}} = -e^{2a\pi i}\int_{-\rho}^{\rho} \frac{e^{ax}}{1+e^{x}} = -e^{2a\pi i} \int_{\gamma_1} \frac{e^{az}}{1+e^{z}} dz $

Comment: PS: When creating contours look for symmetries and where the integrand decays/blows-up. It comes with practice.

Comment: PSS: The integral will converge for $|\operatorname{Re}(a)| < 1$ and converges to $\pi \csc(\pi a)$, as confirmed by the residue theorem